# how to catch output from a subprocess?

Tags: io-redirection, perl

I am trying to catch the password prompt of sftp, but somehow it is not from STDIN or STDERR. It possibly comes from a sub-process.

The following is my test. I tried to redirect the password prompt to a file. I tried file handle number 1 through 4. None worked.

```
mypc:/home/myname$ sftp localhost >/tmp/junk
myname@localhost's password:

mypc:/home/myname$ sftp localhost 2>/tmp/junk
myname@localhost's password:

mypc:/home/myname$ sftp localhost 3>/tmp/junk
myname@localhost's password:

mypc:/home/myname$ sftp localhost 4>/tmp/junk
myname@localhost's password:
```

This is my OS

```
mypc:/home/myname$ uname -a
Linux mypc 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

mypc:/home/myname$ which sftp
/usr/bin/sftp
```

The reason I need to catch it is because I am writing a Perl script to test sftp connection. I could have used Perl's Expect module if I were allowed to install it inside my work place.

Thank you

Comment: Related: [*How/why does `ssh` output to tty when both stdout and stderr are redirected?*](https://superuser.com/q/1557557/432690) `sftp` uses `ssh` as transport.

Comment: that must be it. I read it. it makes sense

Comment: You should be able to install Perl modules locally under your home directory

Comment: agree. Thank you. I just realized that Expect.pm is just 1 file. I can just copy it to my local folder.

Comment: @oldpride or use `cpanm` which allows you to install where you want.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski could you reproduce the relevant points here so we can mark this as answered?

Comment: agree. or mark the question as duplicate question of @KamilMaciorowski's link. I cannot find a way to mark it by myself.

Comment: @terdon I'm not convinced this would be the Right Thing. IMO the question begs for a good solution specific to Perl; few comments seem to be on the right track already. I do not know Perl nor the "ecosystem" of it, I cannot cover this part.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski this question isn't asking how to install perl modules locally (which is very easy to do with `cpanm`), it is asking about capturing the ssh/sftp prompt and that seems like a useful question to have answered.

Comment: all, no worries. If none of you post the answer in a week, I will summarize our discussion into an answer.

Comment: "it is asking about capturing the ssh/sftp prompt" – In my opinion answering only this would be like answering only Y in [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310), when we already know what X is. X involves Perl. I cannot address the Perl part. I'm not going to write an answer, because I do not enjoy writing answers I myself find mediocre or incomplete. Anyone who wants to post an answer, go ahead; I will consider upvoting it even if it does not address the Perl part. And there is no need to mention my input in any answer.

Comment: I posted the answer. Hopefully it covers X and Y. haha. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why the password prompt cannot be caught by a simple direction?**

- The prompt likely comes from a child process.
- This may be a special design so that the prompt will not be mixed with stdout and stderr which users are likely to catch.

Reference: [How/why does ssh output to tty when both stdout and stderr are redirected?](https://superuser.com/questions/1557557/how-why-does-ssh-output-to-tty-when-both-stdout-and-stderr-are-redirected)

**2. How to catch it?**

we can use Perl's Expect module. Test is shown below

```
myname@mypc:/mnt/c/users/myname$ perl -MExpect -e 'print ${Expect->spawn("sftp localhost")->expect(3, [qr/.+/])}[2], "\n";'
umyname@localhost's password:

myname@mypc:/mnt/c/users/myname$ perl -MExpect -e 'print ${Expect->spawn("sftp localhost")->expect(3, [qr/.+/])}[2], "\n";'  >/tmp/junk
```

This basically groups everything from tty into stdout.